# How to format a sequence numbers into this kind of format "000000000001" in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two tables name seed and system. In the Seed table i have this column name receiptid and the data type is nvarchar while  In the system table I have a LastOR column.  In the lastOR column I want to update the LastOR Value with this "00000000001" and the seed table will increment to 2 and so on.
How will I able to achieve this kind of format?

LastOR
0000000001

SeedTable
1

Comment: Last**OR**?  If that's a string representation of bits there are better ways (i.e. a numeric) ..

Comment: because that is the kind of format our companies want it should be series of numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given `int x = 10` the cleanest way is to:

```
string str = x.ToString("D10");
```

or you may prefer:

```
string str = string.Format("{0:D10}", x);
```

For further reference:

[MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN: Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)